# How to install new font on Android 10 and set it as default monospaced?

Tags: fonts, root-access

I'd like to change the default monospaced font on my rooted Android phone. This is because of things like this, where characters don't render correctly:

[image]

The rectangle is supposed to be the "ɒ" character. I know that it works with Deja Vu Sans Mono, so I'd like to change the monospaced font to that.

I've seen methods that change the system default font, but not specifically the default monospaced one.

Some more information:

- Android 10, rooted
- Oneplus 7